# Why is easier to measure directly the rate of increase of the volume than the rate of increase of the radius?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, calculus, gas, volume

I'm reading a Calculus textbook and it says:

> If we are pumping air into a balloon, both the volume and the radius
> of the balloon are increasing and their rates of increase are related
> to each other. But it is much easier to measure directly the rate of
> increase of the volume than the rate of increase of the radius.

Why is that? Don't we need to know the radius in the first place before measuring the volume? Knowing the radius we can check its rate of increase of it first.

Answer (score 1):

If $V = kr^3$ (assuming some homologous shape change then $k$ is a constant), then
$$ \frac{dV}{dr} = 3kr^2 = 3\frac{V}{r}$$
$$ \frac{dV}{V} = 3 \frac{dr}{r}$$

i.e. the fractional change in the volume is 3 times the fractional change in the radius. If you have fixed fractional measurement precision - i.e. if your measurement error in radius is 1%, that leads to a 3% measurement error in volume. Or, you can say that the relative rate of change of volume is three time the relative rate of radius change.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood this properly. Does this mean that a small measurement error in the radius leads to a bigger resultant error in the calculated volume?

Comment: @Jon, yes, three times the percentage error.

Answer (score 1):

You could just put the balloon on a weighing machine. The density of water is constant. You could measure $\frac{dV}{dt}$ by $\frac{dV(t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{dm(t)}{dt}$, where $\rho$ is the density of water and $m(t)$ is the mass of the water at time $t$ measured by the weighing machine. This relation can be obtained by differentiating $m(t)=\rho V(t)$.

The above seems significantly more convenient than setting up a ruler and precisely aligning it with the center and end points of the balloon.